# Third party SCIP files was not found when I build the source code of OR-Tools in compile OR-Tools using tools\make cc

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, or-tools

I have made new file '**Makefile.local**' and add "**WINDOWS_SCIP_DIR=c:/Program Files/SCIPOptSuite**" to the file.

SCIP is also compiled and the file path is correct.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

We have recently updated the installation instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/cpp/source_windows

Can you check them against what you did?

Thanks

Comment: This is the way how I installed it. There is a question of **Prerequisite (Optional): Third-party solvers** in the fourth step that ask **copy scip.dll file to bin directory of OR-Tools**. But I cannot find bin directory. So I didn't copy the file. Does this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: 1) Can you explain how did you build SCIP optsuite ?
2) Makefile doesn't support space in path so "Program Files" won't work IMHO try to use the compressed name instead program~1 IIRC

Answer (score 1):

You must use a path without space since Makefile can't support it everywhere on a windows prompt (e.g. wildcard function in Makefile inside a if command).

if you have installed SCIP using the SCIPOptSuite 6.0.2 64bits Windows installer it should be located in `%ProgramFiles%\SCIPOptSuite 6.0.2` first you need to find the short name version for each directories

```
dir "%ProgramFiles%*" /x
...
Directory of C:\
01/06/2020  10:35 AM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files

dir "%ProgramFiles%\SCIP*" /x
...
01/06/2020  10:35 AM    <DIR>          SCIPOP~1.2   SCIPOptSuite 6.0.2
```

so in my case I can use:

```
set WINDOWS_SCIP_DIR=C:\PROGRA~1\SCIPOP~1.2
```

then you can check using:

```
cd <path_to_your_ortools_source_install>
set PATH=%PATH%;tools;tools\win
make check_third_party
```

to test you can run the sample examples/integer_programming.cc using:

```
make rcc_integer_programming
```